# TCP connection from docker image to c#

Tags: c#, image, docker, tcp

First of all I got 2 console applications. One should be the client the other one the listener.

The client is the program that is containerized in docker. The other one I use on my PC.

Now the problem is that I'm trying to connect the client to my listener. If I test it on my local pc it works just fine but when I build it as image and start it it won't connect.

Client:

```
TcpClient tcpClient;
do
{
    tcpClient = new TcpClient("IP", PORT);
} while (!tcpClient.Connected);
```

Listener:

```
var tcpListener = new TcpListener(PORT);
var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

As I said before local it works but when put in docker image it won't.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "tcpconnector.dll"]
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build -t tcpconnector .

docker run -d --name connector tcpconnector
```

The container starts and runs perfectly but won't connect to my listener. If I change the direction and the listener is inside the image I'm exposing the port I'm listening on like this:

```
docker run -d -p PORT --name listener IMAGE
```

That works !! But I can't get it to work the other way around.

Comment: Where is the port number in the docker command?  The docker listener has a port number but the connector does not have a port number.

Comment: Does the client need a port number tho? I mean I tried using the port im listening on via: -p PORT but still not working. As far as I understand is that you only need a port when you want to expose the image towards the external world aka something wants to establish a connection towards the image not the image towards external world.

Comment: The server (listener) and client must both use same port number.  Docket is probably defaulting to port 25 when the port number is not specified.  The endpoint for the listener should be IPANY and the client should connect to the PC Name or IP address.  Sometimes the IP will work and not Name (or reverse) because the IP masks are set wrong on machine and you will work one direction but not other.

Comment: I initialized both, listener aswell as client to port 12345. Do I have to expose the container when I'm trying to connect outgoing? I read that by default every outgoing port is exposed when using docker (for the docker containers!). And if so which port do I have to expose? docker run -p 12345 doesn't work.

Comment: Only one port need to be specified.  Not sure what the term "exposed" means.

Comment: Well I found the "problem". It sure has something todo with windows. If I try it on linux (clients inside image on linux host aswell as listener on linux host) it works. If the listener is on a windows server or pc it won't work. Gonna look into firewall stuff etc.

Comment: Try replacing the IP address with the computer name and see if it works.  You may not have the IP routing setup correctly and Computer Name may work.